# How do you bootstrap a virtualenv on windows?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm in the process of setting up testing and staging servers in preparation for a Django upgrade project. After reading about virtualenv it sounded like it should be possible to automate the creation of an environment with the correct packages installed, e.g. by piping the output of pip freeze into pip install.  This seems to work fine for most packages, however, some packages aren't pip installable (on Windows) e.g. PIL, pycrypto, MySQLdb, lxml, pymssql, psyco...  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build C modules, you need [a working toolchain](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Building%20Python%20with%20the%20free%20MS%20C%20Toolkit). You could also use Python in a Linux virtual machine if you prefer.

Comment: We deploy on both linux and Windows, so we'll have to be able to do both (linux isn't causing that many problems though ;-)  I'll look into setting up a windows toolchain, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's possible that installing Cygwin, will provide a nice python and toolchain and working pip/easy_install out of the box.